# How to remove unnamed item in JSON file with jq

Tags: json, terminal

I have a JSON file I'm trying to edit through the terminal. The file looks similar to this:

```
{
     "layouts_table_label": "gMapsLayouts",
     "layouts": [
       {
         "id": "LAYOUT_TOWN_1",
         "name": "Town1_Layout",
         "border_filepath": ...location_to_path
       },
       {
         "id": "LAYOUT_TOWN_2",
         "name": "Town2_Layout",
         "border_filepath": ...location_to_path
       },
       {
         "id": "LAYOUT_TOWN_3",
         "name": "Town3_Layout",
         "border_filepath": ...location_to_path
       }
     ]
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is going through the file to remove whichever block contains the input name.

I have tried:

```
map=$mapName"_Layout"
jq -n --arg MAP $map 'del(.layouts[] | select(.name? == [$MAP]))' layouts.json
```

And all I get is "jq: error (at ): Cannot iterate over null (null)".

The $mapName variable is the name of the town (eg. "Town2") entered by the user.

The program is currently in the directory of the layouts.json file if that helps.

I am somewhat new to the terminal and JSON things, so I have a feeling it's a super simple problem that I just can't see. Any help and criticism is appreciated.